# In check_tzones(e1, e2) : 'tzone' attributes are inconsistent

Tags: r, datetime, posixct

What is the significance of the following warning:

```
> t1 <- as.POSIXct("2021-10-03 9:30:00", tz = 'America/New_York')
> t2 <- as.POSIXct("2021-10-03 9:30:00", tz = 'Europe/Brussels')
> t1 > t2
[1] TRUE
Warning message:
In check_tzones(e1, e2) : 'tzone' attributes are inconsistent
```

I am comparing 2 datetimes, one in New York, the other in Brussels and wish to know which timedate comes after the other in "universal time". The underlying R representation is UTC as POSIXct (seconds after 1970), the comparison can be made numerically, and the answer is correct: `t1`. Why should I care that `tzone` is different? I must be missing something important here?

Comment: I presume it is a warning meant for users who are expecting their datetimes to be in the same time zone, since I imagine that in many contexts users could be dealing with local times only.